# Concatenating the values of column and putting back to same row again

Tags: python, pandas

```
    Customer    Material ID Bill Quantity    
0   1           64578       100                                    
1   2           64579       58                                          
2   3           64580       36                                    
3   4           64581       45          
4   5           64582       145
```

We have to concatenate the 0th index material id and 1st index material id and put it into the 0th index material id record.
similarly 1,2 3,4
The result should contain  only catenated records.

Answer (score 0):

Just `shift` the data and combine the columns.

```
df.assign(new_ID=df["Material ID"] + df.shift(-1)["Material ID"])

   Customer  Material ID  Bill  Quantity    new_ID
0         0        64578   100       NaN  129157.0
1         1        64579    58       NaN  129159.0
2         2        64580    36       NaN  129161.0
3         3        64581    45       NaN  129163.0
4         4        64582   145       NaN       NaN
```

If you need to concatenate it as a `str` type then the following would work.

```
df["Material ID"] = df["Material ID"].astype(str)
df.assign(new_ID=df["Material ID"] + df.shift(-1)["Material ID"])

   Customer Material ID  Bill  Quantity      new_ID
0         0       64578   100       NaN  6457864579
1         1       64579    58       NaN  6457964580
2         2       64580    36       NaN  6458064581
3         3       64581    45       NaN  6458164582
4         4       64582   145       NaN         NaN
```

Comment: The OP said concatenate, the columns also say "ID", so maybe an `.astype(str)` is in order?

Comment: you're assuming, OP can clarify if this does not meet the requirements

Comment: I always understand concatenate as "a" + "b" to "ab", that's how all the APIs also work.  To mean 5 + 4 -> 9, I use add or sum, so do the APIs.  I'm not sure what is the additional assumption here, the OP clearly says "concatenate", anyway, just thought I mention it.  Maybe, just to be complete, you could include both in your answer?

Comment: Its not concatinating, the above solution is adding the values in material id column

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'assign'
As df['Material ID] is series.

Comment: It’s no assigning to the Series but the df, not sure where you see it assigning to the Series

Comment: @suvayu added the approach per the comments from OP

Comment: @gold_cy After converting to str it worked